# How can you check if an array contains a duplicate? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Start with an empty array, and add the numbers 1 - 10 RANDOMLY only allowing a number to be repeated once.
eg: when generated, the array would contain two 1's, two 2's, and so on. [1, 1, 2, 2,... 9, 9, 10, 10]

```
arr = []

getrandomNum() => {
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 1;}
  arr.push(randomNum)
```

This example allows more than two of the same number to be generated and I'm not sure what the logic would be not allow more than two 1's or two 5's and so on.

The end result will be apart of a bigger picture; a numbers games like the one on Countdown https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)

Comment: I can think of two options: 1) create an array of all possible numbers (two of each number), randomly produce a number based on the length of that array, pop the number off the “all possible numbers” array, and push on to your randomised array; 2) as you generate your random number, loop through the array to see if the count of that number is <= 2. If so, push the random number on to the array.

Comment: I don't know if this feels more like homework, or just a really poor question; could you please read the "*[ask]*" guidance, and then [edit] your question to improve it? And, also, show the "*[mcve]*" code you attempted when you tried to solve this problem yourself, tell us what you expected it to do, where you got stuck? What went wrong, and in what way?

Comment: If you want every number to be repeated twice, do it like this: Generate a random number, check if it's already in the array. If not, push it twice. Repeat this.

Comment: You can check if the first occurrence (`indexOf()`) is the same or different as the last occurrence (`lastIndexOf()`) of a particular number. If they're different, the number occurs (at least) two times in the array and shouldn't be added again.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a random number and check if it is already there in the result array and push it if not. But there is a possibility here, theoretically, that random number continue to generate the same set of number and ends up with an infinity loop. So in order to overcome this, we can have a separate values array and remove each item from it after picking randomly from it.

Sample visualization of the logic:

```js
/**
 * Start with an empty array, and add the numbers 1 - 10 RANDOMLY 
 * only allowing a number to be repeated once. 
 * eg: when generated, the array would contain two 1's, two 2's, and so on. 
 * [1, 1, 2, 2,... 9, 9, 10, 10]
**/

// result array
const result = []


// Define an array with values from 1 to 10
const baseValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
renderBaseValues();

function updateResult() {
  if(baseValues.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // Generate random number between 0 to 9 
  let maxRandomValue = baseValues.length;
  let currentRandomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRandomValue);

  // push random value two time
  result.push(baseValues[currentRandomIndex]);
  result.push(baseValues[currentRandomIndex]);

  // remove this from base values to avoid adding again
  baseValues.splice(currentRandomIndex, 1);
  renderBaseValues();
  renderResult();
  setTimeout(() => {
    updateResult();    
  }, 1000)
}

updateResult();

/// Render functions --
function renderBaseValues() {
  const el = document.getElementById("main");
  el.innerHTML = "";
  baseValues.forEach(val => {
    el.innerHTML += `<span class="base-val">${val}</span>` 
  });
}

function renderResult() {
  const el = document.getElementById("result");
  el.innerHTML = "";
  result.forEach(val => {
    el.innerHTML += `<span class="result">${val}</span>` 
  });
}
```

```css
.row {
  margin: 5px;
}

.base-val, .result {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
}


.result {
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<h3>Base values</h3>
<div id="main" class="row"></div>
<h3>Result values</h3>
<div id="result" class="row"></div>
```